What was the ' drown with the millstone' punishment of Lk 17:2?
We read  in Lk 17:1-2 ( KJV):

Then said he unto the disciples, It is impossible but that offences will come: but woe unto him, through whom they come!
It were better for him that a millstone were hanged about his neck, and he cast into the sea, than that he should offend one of these little ones.

Jesus appears to be referring to a summary punishment without formal  trial, as in the case of stoning to death for blasphemy. While stoning was prescribed in Mosaic law, it is not clear if the punishment of drowning with a millstone (so heavy as to be moved by donkeys ), was prescribed . Or was it a Roman punishment like crucifixion ? How do Bible scholars narrate the punishment mentioned by Jesus in Lk 17:2 ?

The assumption that this was "a summary punishment without formal trial" would need to have some evidence to substantiate that thought. Mention of this happening at sea might indicate events on a ship but, again, evidence for this would need to be presented. And the stoning to death for blasphemy without formal trial was not God's law, but an attempt by some who hated Jesus to kill him without recourse to Roman law. Why would Bible scholars need to 'explain' Lk.17:2?

Thanks, Anne. Jn 8 narrates the Pharisees picking up stones to kill Jesus . Elsewhere we see ' possessed' swines drowning in the sea. Of course,big lakes were also called sea at that time. –
K
.. And we see the. ' adulterous ' woman being brought to Jesus for his nod , to be stoned to death. That too, if implemented, would be a summary punishment.

Perhaps, the Jewish leaders cleverly substituted the need for judgement by competent authority, with matching testimony of witnesses. That requirement too was waived off at Jesus trial in that there was not agreement between those who witnessed against him. As you say, the leaders had taken thel law into their hands. No wonder Pilate asked them to judge Jesus according to their own law !

(Please ignore spelling errors . My Android is not that good at editing comments . Thanks.

Ellicott answers this question about the millstone of Luke 17:2 in his comments about the parallel passage on Matt 18:6 -

That a millstone were hanged about his neck.—The word for “millstone” indicates the larger stone-mill, in working which an ass
was commonly employed, as distinguished from the smaller handmill of
Luke 17:35. The punishment was not recognised in the Jewish law, but
it was in occasional use among the Greeks (Diod. Sic. xvi. 35), and
had been inflicted by Augustus (Sueton. Aug. lxvii.) in cases of
special infamy. Jerome states (in a note on this passage) that it was
practised in Galilee, and it is not improbable that the Romans had
inflicted it upon some of the ringleaders of the insurrection headed
by Judas of Galilee. Our Lord’s words, on this assumption, would come
home with a special vividness to the minds of those who heard them.
The infamy of offending one of the “little ones” was as great as that
of those whoso crimes brought upon them this exceptional punishment.

Barnes is similar:

It were better for him that a millstone ... - Mills, anciently, were either turned by hand (see the notes at Matthew 24:41), or by
beasts, chiefly by mules. These last were of the larger kind, and the
original words denote that it was this kind that was intended. This
was one mode of capital punishment practiced by the Greeks, Syrians,
Romans, and by some other nations. The meaning is, it would be better
for him to have died before he had committed the sin. To injure, or to
cause to sin, the feeblest Christian, will be regarded by Christ as a
most serious offence, and will be punished accordingly.


First, as word about the crime, then the punishment. The OP speaks of "offending" one of the disciples. The crime here is understood by modern translators to be to cause a Christian to "stumble" or "fall into sin." The same may be said of the verb "offend" in the Sermon on the Mount, which is likewise understood to mean "cause a person to sin" rather than literally "offend."
Matthew 5 KJV

if thy right eye offend thee, pluck it out, and cast it from thee: for
it is profitable for thee that one of thy members should perish, and
not that thy whole body should be cast into hell. 30 And if thy right
hand offend thee, cut it off, and cast it from thee: for it is
profitable for thee that one of thy members should perish, and not
that thy whole body should be cast into hell.

As with the example of the millstone in the OP, blinding and cutting off the right hand were both punishments used in the Roman Empire. So perhaps Jesus was not referring to an extra-judicial punishment but a legal one.  However, I would not be too quick to presume - as Barnes and Ellicott do in @Dottard's answer - that Jesus envisions capital punishment or worse for "offending one of these little ones." Surely the person who taught us to love our enemies and forgive those who trespass against us would not impose a punishment so out of proportion with the crime. Both Catholic and Protestant  authorities did impose the death penalty on those who attempted to lead Christians into heresy, but this understanding of Jesus' teaching must be rejected. Rather, Jesus is speaking in hyperbole, as he did when he taught that we should pluck out our own eye or cut off our right hand if it offends us.
Conclusion: while drowning a person by using a heavy weight was indeed a form of punishment in the Roman world, Jesus did not suggest those who "offend one of these little ones" deserves death by drowning or worse. He referred either to the weight of conscience, or to the fate of the sinner in the afterlife.
